# How many functions f : [n] → [n] are there for which there exists exactly one i ∈ [n] satisfying f(i) = i?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

As the title asks, I'm looking for the number of functions $f : [n] \rightarrow [n]$ for which there exists exactly one $i \in [n]$ satisfying $f(i) = i$.

I know the number of functions $f : [n] \rightarrow [n]$ is $n^n.$ I'm looking for how I would make that more specific as to only find the functions where there exists exactly one $i \in [n]$ satisfying $f(i) = i$.

EDIT: I think I may have come up with a solution, and verification would be greatly appreciated as my textbook offers no solutions. My thinking is this:

Because there's exactly one $f(i) = i$, any function satisfying our criteria must have all but one $f(i) \neq i$. So, for each $i \in [n]$, we have $(n-1)$ options for $f(i)$. This is true for all but one $i \in [n]$, where the number of options for $f(i)$ is $1$. So, my proposed solution is $(n-1)^{(n-1)}$. This provides us with with the number of functions $f : [n] \rightarrow [n]$ where every $i \in [n]$ satisfies $f(i) \neq i$. Then there is the single case of $f(i) = i$, which does not change the number of possible solutions from $(n-1)^{n-1}$.

EDIT 2: **Solved**. My logic above was ignoring the fact that there are $n$ choices for the element $i$ where $f(i) = i$. My solution above finds the number of functions $f : [n] \rightarrow [n]$ where $(n-1)$ elements satisfy $f(j) = j$, and one fixed $i \in n$ always satisfies $f(i) = i$. By multiplying this number, $(n-1)^{n-1}$, by the number of choices for the fixed element $i$, we get $n \times (n-1)^{n-1}$, which is the answer.

Comment: Do you know about *derangements*?

Comment: @AnginaSeng I have not heard of or worked with derangements - this question is from the first chapter in _A Walk Through Combinatorics_, so I'm still working with basic stuff (permutations, combinations, and bijections). I did look up derangements out of curiosity, though. If my understanding is correct, the derangement $!(n-1)$ would give me all the functions $f : [n] \rightarrow [n]$ such that $f(j) \neq j$. Then, for the one element $f(i) = i$, I could come to this solution: $!(n-1) \times n$, to account for $(n-1)$ non-fixed elements plus one $i \in [n]$ mapped to itself. Is this right?

Comment: @AnginaSeng - derangements are also what came to my mind first but we're both assuming the problem is more advanced than it is.  :)  The OP question does not require that the non-fixed elements be non-repeated (i.e. be a derangement).

Comment: @antkam I understand the problem as I believe it was meant to be solved, but I'd love to have either of you (or anyone else) check my logic with derangements above. They seem interesting & useful, but I don't want to get in over my head and start making things up that are totally wrong. It seems like $!(n-1)$ would be equivalent to $(n-1)^{n-1}$ in this case, which would easily fit into my main solution.

Comment: @chrisT - you are correct about the derangement version (variant) of this problem.  I have not read your book but (possible spoiler! :D ) I would not be surprised one bit if derangements are in a later chapter and perhaps even this exact variant is in the exercises.

Comment: No.  Derangements are something very specific.  A derangement is very specifically a **permutation** with no fixed points and as such must be bijective, both surjective and injective.  The current problem has no such requirement on surjectivity or injectivity.  The number of derangements on $n-1$ elements is not $(n-1)^{(n-1)}$, and the proposed identity that $!(n-1)=(n-1)^{(n-1)}$ is incorrect

Comment: It is true that the number of **permutations** who have exactly one fixed point can be found to be $!(n-1)\times n$ however, I must stress that this is a different problem than the one asking for the number of *functions* who have exactly one fixed point.

Comment: @JMoravitz I see what you mean. What I found with $n \times !(n-1)$ is the number of functions $f : [n] \rightarrow [n]$ such that there is exactly one $i \in [n]$ satisfying $f(i) = i$, but I've assumed something more about all other $j \in [n]$. I've found the number of functions that are bijective for all but one $j \in [n]$ with exactly one $f(i) = i$ for some $i \in [n]$. This is wrong because the question does not suggest that we cannot have two 'inputs' $x \in [n]$ associated with the same 'output' $y \in [n]$. How would one solve this using derangements, then? Thank you.

Comment: @antkam A simple check of my previous solution using derangements really shows the problem. For $n = 3$, the correct solution of $n \times (n-1)^{n-1}$ gives $12$, which can be verified correct by listing all $27$ possible permutations of $[3]$ and eliminating ones that don't satisfy our requirements. The solution $n \times !(n-1)$ for $n = 3$ gives the answer $3$, because $!(3-1) = !2 = 1$, which can also easily be shown by showing cases. Clearly, $n \times !(n-1)$ is excluding $9$ possible functions - those that are not bijective, but still satisfy all our requirements.

Comment: "*how does one solve* **this** *using derangements then?*"  You don't.  For the same reason that you don't use a screwdriver to hammer in a nail, you should use appropriate tools for the task at hand.  While derangements are indeed a useful tool for other problems, they are not a useful tool here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT since this seems like homework.

Pick a specific $i$ for which $f(i) = i$.  Now for each of the remaining $f(j)$ how many choices are there?

Comment: Not homework, self study from a book without solutions. See my proposed solution in my original post; I followed this line of thinking and think the solution may be $(n-1)^{(n-1)}$.

Comment: You are confusing the $i$ which is fixed and the other $i$'s which are not (which is why I use index $j$ for the latter instead).  $(n-1)^{n-1}$ counts the no. of functions where a specific $i$, e.g. $i=7$, is fixed and all the other $j$'s are not.  But then you have to sum over all choices of the fixed element $i$ itself.  So the final answer is $n \times (n-1)^{n-1}$.  Am I making sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. I felt like something was missing from my answer. So, in my initial answer, I found the number of functions where $(n-1)$ elements all satisfied $f(j) \neq j$, but the $i \in [n]$ was a fixed $i \in [n]$. $n \times (n-1)^{n-1}$ accounts for the fact that we need to let $i$ be ANY $i \in [n]$, not just one particular $i \in [n]$ that is consistent between every function. I'm struggling to put this into words, but is this the general idea here? I'm trying to understand this deeply since it's self-study and I have time.

Comment: You are exactly right.  BTW a good trick (esp. in combinatorics) is to try small examples.  Well $0^0$ is a bit ambiguous so lets start with $n=2$.  Do you agree there are $2\times 1^1 =2$ such functions?  Even for $n=3$ you should be able to easily list out the $3 \times 2^2 = 12$ such functions. (At worst, list all $27$ unrestricted functions and cross out the ones that don't fit.)